# Plugin 1 Deleting Plugin 2 Classes (Maven)

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am trying to generate JAVA classes WSDLs and XSDs, but when I run mvn clean install, I see that the classes are generating from my first plugin in the logs, but my second plugin just deletes them. I have my build section written like this:

```
<build>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-wsdl-to-java</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
            </configuration>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-xsd-to-java</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                .
                .
                .
                .
            </configuration>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I reverse the plugins the classes generate fine without anything being over-written/deleted. I could keep it that way if i wanted to and move on, but I would like to know what am I doing wrong in this case. I am semi-new to Maven, so still understanding all the ins and outs. Do i have to wrap them around "pluginManagement" or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

it really depends on, how you configured the output folders of this two plugins.

The defaults are `${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/wsimport` and `${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxb` so I wouldn't expect them NOT to be overwritten.

anyway: if both plugins are meant to run within the same phase, then their order within POM defines their execution order - even `pluginManagement` would not change this. so there is nothing wrong about this

Comment: I have set the output for the java classes as `${basedir}\src\main\java\` because that is where I want all my java files to end up.

Comment: ok - this is really bad practice if these plugins are executed for every `mvn clean install`. Why do you want them mixed up with the other code within `src\main\java`

Comment: I never thought it would be deleted, their package declarations should keep them distinct and separate from each other shouldn't it? Or maybe i am setting a flag wrong in my configuration that is cleaning the folder before processing the files?

Comment: the `xjc` goal of `jaxb2-maven-plugin` has a flag [clearOutputDir](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.3.1/xjc-mojo.html#clearOutputDir) which is true by default